# cite and citep do the same thing for the acmart package

Tags: citing, natbib, amsart

The `acmart` package is directly available on Overleaf and can be downloaded here in section 2: https://www.acm.org/publications/authors/submissions

MWE:

```
\documentclass{acmart}
%\documentclass{article}
\citestyle{acmauthoryear}
\begin{filecontents}{mytestbib.bib}
@book{goossens93,
    author = "Frank Mittelbach and Michel Goossens  and Johannes Braams and David Carlisle  and Chris Rowley",
    title = "The {LaTeX} Companion",
    year = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\nobibliography*

\begin{document}

Using \texttt{citep}: \citep{goossens93}.

Using \texttt{cite}: \cite{goossens93}.

What I expect from \texttt{cite}: Mittelbach et al. [1993] (this is what you get if you comment \texttt{documentclass\{acmart\}} and \texttt{citestyle\{acmauthoryear\}} and uncomment \texttt{documentclass\{article\}}).


\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{mytestbib}

\end{document}
```

Result: [image]

After switching the document class to article, the desired behavior is achieved:

[image]

Comment: You can just use `\citet`.Or even `\renewcommand{\cite}{\citet}` if you want. Natbib sometimes treats `\cite` like `\citep` and sometimes like `\citet` but actually says in its documentation that plain `\cite` should be avoided. (Actually it looks like acmart.cls actually has `\let\cite\citep` in it. )

Comment: @frabjous Thank you - if you leave this as the answer, then I will mark it as correct

Comment: OK I added an answer. You should change your question and its title from `amsart` to `acmart`, however, since both exist but you mean the latter.

Comment: @frabjous Of course you are right -- thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate and reiterate what I wrote in the comments, natbib defines two primary citation commands `\citep` and `\citet`. For author-year citations:

- `\citep{mittelbach93}` generates something like **[Mittelbach et al., 1993]** with the name inside the brackets or parentheses
- `\citet{mittelbach93}` generates something like **Mittelbach et al. [1993]** with the name outside the brackets/parentheses

About plain `\cite` without t or p following, [the natbib documentation](https://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/natbib.pdf) says this:

> Both `\citep` and `\citet` are defined by natbib and are thus not
> standard. The standard LATEX command `\cite` should be avoided, because
> it behaves like `\citet` for author–year citations, but like `\citep` for
> numerical ones.

So documents using natbib sometimes treat `\cite` as `\citep` and sometimes treat it like `\citet`. One would think that if you use `\citestyle{acmauthoryear}` in an acm document to get author-year citations it would treat `\cite` like `\citet`, but `acmart.cls` overrides that and has `\let\cite\citep`, so `\cite` behaves like `\citep`.

If you take natbib's documentation's advice, you should avoid `\cite` and then use `\citet` everywhere you want the name outside the brackets. But if you're too used to using `\cite` or your document is already written with `\cite`, and you want to make `\citet`-behavior default, you can redefine `\cite`:

```
\renewcommand{\cite}{\citet}
```